# Reading an entire file using C++, ignoring false-positive EOFs

Tags: c++, file, fstream, ifstream

I'm doing an small Huffman compression-encryption program, and during the decompression of the file, my current getFile method (that should return the whole file as a String) ends sooner than expected, and trying to force it to read after a false-positive EOF (maybe? It's consistent with the same string) causes the program to crash.

Here's my current method:

```
string getFile(string route){
    ifstream reader; 
    string s=""; 
    reader.open(route); 
    if(reader.bad())return "FAILURE TO OPEN FILE"; 
    reader.read((char*)&dictionary.weight, sizeof(int)); // There's an int in the beggining
    // It describes the original ammount of chars there were in the original file. 
    while(!reader.eof()){ s+= reader.get() } 
    reader.close(); 
    return s; 
}
```

Comment: Try opening the file with `ios::bin`

Answer (score 2):

You should open the file in *binary mode*. This means that no translation should be performed between the contents of the file, and what your program sees. The default is called *text mode* and various transformations may occur there; e.g. in Windows typically `\r\n` is translated to `\n`, and byte 26 may appear to be end-of-file.

```
reader.open(route, ios::binary);
```

Also, [don't use `eof` in a loop condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)